# How can I force my pci card usb bus numbers to stay the same after reboot?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I have a few *identical* usb sound cards and wrote a udev rule so they each get a persistent name matching the specific port they are attached to. Now  I added a pci usb 3.0 card and that is playing around with usb bus numbers. sometimes the pci usb gets loaded before the built-in usb and has a lower bus number and sometimes after and gets a higher bus number.

What can I do to force the bus numbers of the built-in and pci card?

If that can't work what can I do to get persistent device names for identical (and without serial numbers) usb devices where the only difference is the port they are attached to?

```
~ $ uname -srvmpio
Linux 4.19.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.12-1~bpo9+1 (2018-12-30) x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux
```

Edit (added different outputs of lsusb -t)
buses 9 and 10 can swap with 5 and 6 seemingly randomly.
added pci usb3.0 card shows up as 5 and 6 in the first output and 9 and 10 in the second.
Sometimes the setup is:

```
/:  Bus 10.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 09.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
```

And othertimes, without hardware change, after reboot it can be:

```
/:  Bus 10.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 09.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
```

Comment: Adding your operating system would help you get an answer. Please [edit] the question and add the correct tag.

Comment: First idea is to modify the udev rules to identify built-in USB root hubs, and use the USB port structure (`lsusb -t`) once you matched the hub. `udevadm` helps to identify attributes you want to match against.

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to do. I was (am) asking how to use udev to give permanent structure to the usb hubs and ports.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/360336/192715

Comment: @AlexP. That is different. I am having an issue because the devices are getting different paths after reboot even _without_ hardware changes. I will update my question with different `lsusb -t` output.